# Need help making 2 iframes reponsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

So I'm kind of a noob and I put 2 iframes underneath each other and they look completely fine (picture)[image: this is how it looks like without making the window smaller] until I need them to be responsive when i make the window smaller. This is my code:

```html
<div id="fh5co-main">

  <aside id="fh5co-hero" class="js-fullheight">

    <iframe width="1520" height="500" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/f4vA1y7-k_E" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>

    <iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="chat_embed" src="https://www.twitch.tv/embed/hydro/chat" height="470" width="1520">
</iframe>

</div>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make width="100%" on both iframes